# How to un-do restricting website's access to Facebook?

Tags: facebook, authentication

I went to sign up for one of many, many web services (in this case "[Honey](https://www.joinhoney.com/welcome)") which supports logging in with Facebook. When I was prompted what Facebook information I'd like to allow access to, I unchecked the option to get my Email. Upon proceeding, the website stopped me and said email is required. But now, whenever I attempt to login with Facebook again, I'm no longer prompted to allow or dis-allow access in order to give it access to my email.

How can I un-do this restriction so that I can go back and give it access to my email?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Facebook, on top top-right, click on the icon representing a lock to open the Security menu. Go to "See More Settings".

[image]

On the next page, go to "Apps" in the list on the left. This will show a list of all apps which you have allowed to access your Facebook account. Find this one ("Honey") and click on it.

[image]

This will show what pieces of information you have granted. On the bottom of this screen, choose "Remove App".

[image]

And confirm.

[image]

Then, go and sign up again. And don't uncheck that email option!